# Mongoose Azure Cosmos

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

I am running a `count`  query on a mongoDB. But getting the following error.

```
app.get('/doc/count', (req, res) => {
    doc.count(req.query).then((count) => {
        res.send({ count });
    }, (err) => {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});
```

But I am getting the following error. Works good in local mongodb.

```
{
    "name": "MongoError",
    "message": "query in command must target a single shard key",
    "_t": "OKMongoResponse",
    "ok": 0,
    "code": 61,
    "errmsg": "query in command must target a single shard key",
    "$err": "query in command must target a single shard key"
    }
```

Comment: is this a sharded collection? what is the shard key? could you paste an example document?

Comment: Its sharded. But I am not sure about the key. How should I use it in the query if needed?

Comment: @alekseys, shardKey = /ARCHIVEKEY

Comment: Is there any way to use `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` using mongoose?